When is appropriate to use generator expressions in CMake?
I learned CMake recently, from a mix of Udemy courses, Stack Overflow, and other random internet articles, but my learnings did not get into CMake generator expressions.
I recently encountered this snippet of CMake code:
target_compile_options(${EXEC_NAME} PRIVATE
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:-Wno-unsafe-buffer-usage>
)

The syntax is simple enough that I can infer that it sets the -Wno-unsafe-buffer-usage C compiler option.
If I'm not mistaken, the "equivalent" conditional without using generator expressions is:
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
    target_compile_options(${EXEC_NAME} PRIVATE -Wno-unsafe-buffer-usage)
endif()

Because I've not yet properly studied CMake generator expressions, I am probably biased, but the second code-block, i.e. the version without generator expressions, seems easier to read: e.g. the nesting of $<> is slightly obtuse to my untrained eye (purely my anecdotal observation, but when I see CMake generator expressions, they seem to always have nested $<> scopes).
The above two code blocks are just one cherry-picked example where something can be implemented in CMake both with and without generator expressions. My question is: what specific kinds of problems can only be solved with generator expressions -- or why do the two "styles" of CMake code exist? In other words: if every CMake generator expression has an "equivalent" that can be implemented without generator expressions, why have these two different "implementation styles" (I don't know what else to call it)?
(I imagine that generator expressions are something that came along recently, or perhaps in some second "wave" of CMake updates(?) because I haven't yet seen CMake generator expressions covered in introductory CMake tutorials -- introductory material always seems based on the "non-generator expression" syntax)
